# Regex : refuse nothing but a word in the middle of an expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am currently fiddling with TreeTagger and regex and I am trying to get adjective(ADJ) that are after a noun(NOM)

so this example :

```
La DET:ART le
voiture NOM voiture
était   VER:impf    être
rouge   ADJ rouge
à   PRP à
côté    NOM côté
d'  PRP de
un  DET:ART un
arbre   NOM arbre
vert    ADJ vert
.   SENT    .
```

should give us something like:

```
voiture
était   VER:impf    être
rouge   ADJ rouge
```

and

```
arbre
vert    ADJ vert
```

the tricky part is that the regex have to detect if there is a "NOM" between the first "NOM" and the "ADJ"

my current regex

```
Regex rgx2 = new Regex("(?<=NOM[\t])((.|\n)*)ADJ.*");

(?<=NOM[\t]) //preceded by "NOM   "
((.|\n)*) // anything (should be "anything but NOM")
ADJ.* //finish with an adjective
```

does not do that

is there any way to obtain my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

```
(?<=\bNOM\s)(?s)((?:(?!\bNOM\b).)*)\bADJ\b(?-s).*
```

You need to use a singleline (DOTALL) mode for `.` to match newlines, switch to a tempered greedy token (with `(?:(?!\bNOM\b).)*`), and I also suggest to make it safer with the word boundaries `\b`. With the `(?-s).*` at the end, we can disable the singleline mode and match just the rest of the *line*.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5CbNOM%5Cs)(%3Fs)((%3F%3A(%3F!%5CbNOM%5Cb).)*)%5CbADJ%5Cb(%3F-s).*&i=La%20DET%3AART%20le%0D%0Avoiture%20NOM%20voiture%0D%0A%C3%A9tait%20%20%20VER%3Aimpf%20%20%20%20%C3%AAtre%0D%0Arouge%20%20%20ADJ%20rouge%0D%0A%C3%A0%20%20%20PRP%20%C3%A0%0D%0Ac%C3%B4t%C3%A9%20%20%20%20NOM%20c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%0D%0Ad%27%20%20PRP%20de%0D%0Aun%20%20DET%3AART%20un%0D%0Aarbre%20%20%20NOM%20arbre%0D%0Avert%20%20%20%20ADJ%20vert%0D%0A.%20%20%20SENT%20%20%20%20.&o=s)

[image]

And here is a bit more optimized version without a lookbehind (since you are only interested in the capture, you can simply match `NOM`):

```
\bNOM\s(?s:((?:(?!\bNOM\b).)*))\bADJ\b(?-s:.*)
```

See another [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CbNOM%5Cs(%3Fs%3A((%3F%3A(%3F!%5CbNOM%5Cb).)*))%5CbADJ%5Cb(%3F-s%3A.*)&i=La%20DET%3AART%20le%0D%0Avoiture%20NOM%20voiture%0D%0A%C3%A9tait%20%20%20VER%3Aimpf%20%20%20%20%C3%AAtre%0D%0Arouge%20%20%20ADJ%20rouge%0D%0A%C3%A0%20%20%20PRP%20%C3%A0%0D%0Ac%C3%B4t%C3%A9%20%20%20%20NOM%20c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%0D%0Ad%27%20%20PRP%20de%0D%0Aun%20%20DET%3AART%20un%0D%0Aarbre%20%20%20NOM%20arbre%0D%0Avert%20%20%20%20ADJ%20vert%0D%0A.%20%20%20SENT%20%20%20%20.&o=s)

Here, I am also using the `(?s:...)` (enabling DOTALL mode for a part of pattern) and `(?-s:...)` (**dis**abling DOTALL mode for a part of pattern).

Comment: Just wanted to comment on your `(.|\n)*` - it is a very inefficient pattern in regex, and I advise you to never use it in real code. To match any character including a newline, use `(?s)` / `RegexOptions.Singleline` with `.`. Tempered greedy tokens are good when you want to match *the shortest* window between two multicharacter delimiters.